# How to have a continuous timer in firefox XUL?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I would like to have a timer in XUL which will increment as time passes from a given start and end point (triggered by event listeners)

The UI I have set up is as follows:

```
<vbox>
    <label id="asterisk-ext-caller-id-num" value="XXXXX XXX XXX" />
    <label id="asterisk-ext-caller-id-name" value="Blah de blah blah" />

    <timepicker id="asterisk-ext-calltimer" readonly="true" disabled="true" is24HourClock="true" value="00:16:24" />

    <hbox> 

        <button id="asterisk-ext-hold-button" label="Hold"
        oncommand="AsteriskExtPresence.BrowserOverlay.toggleHold();"/>

        <button id="asterisk-ext-hangup-button" label="Hangup"
        oncommand="AsteriskExtPresence.BrowserOverlay.hangupMyChannel();"/>

    </hbox>

</vbox>
```

I'd like to increment the `asterisk-ext-calltimer` element every second to give a count of how long a person has been on the phone for.

I can either start it going (ideal) or query the server for the time every second (not ideal, obvious reasons)

Anyone done this before, or can anyone think how best to get the incrementation on the `timepicker`?

Comment: Why cant you use use setTimer function and update `asterisk-ext-calltimer` element every its tick?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do here exaclty, or what your problem is (post actual code) but [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval)

Answer (score 0):

See [Alternating two colors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval#Example_2.3A_Alternating_two_colors) example on MDN